# Можно ли использовать модули python локально?

Tags: python, python-3.x

можно ли выкачать библиотеки которые используются в скрипте, положить их как-то рядом, или указать их путь, что бы в дальнейшем скрипт за ними не ходил в интернеты, и использовал те, которые уже скачаны?

Comment: Что вам даст ответ "можно" или "нельзя"?

Comment: А скрипт и не ходит в интернеты за модулями.

Comment: как ни крути когда ты устанавливаешь модуль он скачивается на пк,можешь найти его и использовать как душе угодно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Он бегает.

Answer (score 1):

Wheel - современный формат распространения пакетов в Python, который пришел на смену egg.

Для начала вам понадобится последняя версия pip

`pip3 install -U pip`

И пакет для поддержки колес.

`pip3 install wheel`

Удобно будет создать директорию, куда будут упакованы whl пакеты.

`mkdir whls`

Упакуйте все зависимости проекта с помощью wheel.

`pip3 wheel --wheel-dir=whls/ -r requirements.txt --pre --allow-all-external`

эта команда упакует все зависимости проекта в директрию whls, которую вы передаете кому-то. Стоит обратить внимание что некоторые пакеты, например из VCS упакованы не будут, для них требуется в ручную создавать whl через `setup.py bdist_wheel`.

```
cd venv/src/package_name  # идем в директорию с исходниками пакета
python setup.py bdist_wheel --dist-dir /project/dir/whls/  # упаковываем его в whl
```

Установить пакеты:

`pip3 install --no-index --find-links=/whls -r requirements.txt`

Также можно поднять локальный репозиторий PyPi, например https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/, и складировать в него все пакеты проекта, чтобы они были доступны всей команде.

Также сам pip имеет локальный кэш с whl пакетами, которые он скачивает при установке зависимостей, он не будет ходить за пакетом если требуемая версия пакета имеется в кэше.

Answer (score 0):

Все модули python (как стандартные, так и установленные пользователем) находятся в папке
`% корневая папка Python %/Lib`.
У меня python установлен в `D:/Python34/`. Тогда модули нужно искать в `D:/Python34/Lib`.
Вы можете скопировать оттуда нужные вам модули в ваш проект, и в таком случае импортировать модуль с помощью конструкции `import .название`.

Примеры такого импорта:

```py
import .math
from .tkinter import *
```

Соответственно, в таком случае вы должны при передаче файлов проекта на другой компьютер передавать и каталоги модулей, так как теперь они являются частью вашего проекта, равно как и файлы проекта, которые вы создаёте сами.